# Como puedo hacer return redirect a la pagina que llamo a la funcion? Django

Tags: django, login, redirección

> Hola. He creado una seccion de loguin que funciona muy
> bien, pero siempre al logear, va al home, y yo quisiera que volviera a
> la pagina que le pidió que se loguee.
>
> Llamo al logueo desde un link tradicional que esta en la cabecera
> de las paginas:

```
<a style="color:white;"  href="{% url 'logear' %}">Login</a>
```

> El código del views.py donde se realiza el login

```
def logear(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nombre_usuario= form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            contra = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            usuario =  authenticate(username=nombre_usuario, password = contra)
            if usuario is not None:
                login(request,usuario)
                return redirect('Home') ''' Este es el redirect que em gustaria cambiar'''
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Usuario no registrado..!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Informacion Incorrecta..!")
    form=AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "login/login.html",{"form":form})
```

> Muchas Gracias

Comment: Hola Claudio, una solución es meter un parámetro `next` en el formulario, para que luego puedas recuperarlo en tu función `loggear` y redirigir al usuario al lugar correcto. Si no sabes cómo hacerlo te lo pongo en respuestas.

Comment: Gracias Daniel. No lo se...